# git cherry-pick -x: link in details instead of in summary

Tags: git, cherry-pick

Given a commit with the message "foo", i.e. with only a summary part, I do `git cherry-pick -x the_commit`. The result is a new commit with message

```
foo
(cherry picked from commit eb42a6475d2c2e4fff7a1b626ce6e27eec21e886)
```

Now that's not good, because it is a two-line summary, which seems like a bug in git.

But how can I make git make the comment look like below without editing the comment manually?

```
foo

(cherry picked from commit eb42a6475d2c2e4fff7a1b626ce6e27eec21e886)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right that it seems like an oversight. You could send an email to the [git mailing list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git) and see what they think! For now you'll have to handle it yourself, though.

The good way to deal with this would be to avoid it altogether: make the original commit message good. If it's already multi-line, with the blank line in there, the appended line from the cherry-pick will not screw up the format.

To work around it, given that the cherry-picked commit has a one-line message, as you say, you can use the `-e` option for cherry-pick. If you're using Vim, worst case you have to hit `ggo<Esc>ZZ` to take care of it.

Or you could write a prepare-commit-msg hook. All you should need in it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '2s/^(cherry picked/\n&' "$1"
```

Comment: I can't make the original committers (i.e. other people) format their messages in that way.
To edit the message manually, `git commit -x -e` seems like a better solution.

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant `git cherry-pick -x -e`. (Can't edit anymore.)

Comment: @stellar: Oh, duh, you're right. I forgot cherry-pick had that option. Glad you got a response from the mailing list, though!

Comment: @stellar: One other thought - you could use a prepare-commit-msg hook to rewrite the message. Shouldn't be too bad - just check if line two starts with "(cherry picked", and if so, insert a blank line.

Comment: Still not fixed in Git 1.8.1.2 -- Apparently this finally gets fixed in the upcoming Git version: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-cherry-pick-x-improve-handling-of-one-liner-commit-messages-tp7581046p7581055.html